# How to align dropdown button with the rest of the navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I used the outline of the code from we3schools. My problem is that the button is not level with the navbar.

[image: image example]

I couldn't get the code to align where it would let me publish so here is the github link (it's an html file with just the navbar and a css file with just the navbar portion in it).

LINK: https://github.com/Terrancesky/website/tree/main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems everything is fine, You can also check by adding this css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .topnav {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```